# DIV background color change when Hover

Tags: php, html, css, hover

I have looked at a few posts on here but haven't had success with making my div change background color when the mouse hovers. It's a little messy, but bear with me. Here is the html/php code:

```
<a class="hoverTwo" href="https:/doltesting.000webhostapp.com/pageTwo.php">
  <div class="hoverTwo" class="secondSection">
    <p class="hoverTwo" style="background: lightblue;
           border: solid;
           text-align: center;
           font-family: Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans, cursive;">
      <br><br><br>
     <?php=
       echo "Section Two - Unknown";
      ?>
      <br><br><br><br><br>
    </p>
  </div>
</a>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
a.hoverTwo a:hover a:visited a:link {
background: yellow;
color: black; }
```

Comment: Your selector is completely wrong. Do you know how selectors work?

Comment: my CSS is a little shaky, but I have a basic understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get you started, and keep in mind that inline styles override css:

```
<a href="https:/doltesting.000webhostapp.com/pageTwo.php">
    <div class="secondSection">
        <p class="hoverTwo">
            <br><br><br>
            SOME TEXT
            <br><br><br>
        </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

With this in your css:

```
.hoverTwo { background-color:lightblue;color:green; }
.hoverTwo:hover{ background-color:yellow;color:black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
.hoverTwo:hover {
     background-color: blue;
}
```

Also there are some mistakes in your existing css. Notice the commas I added. Also not that your a:hover would be set to the same color as the a itself. So there would be no color change on hover.

```
a.hoverTwo, a:hover, a:visited, a:link {
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Here's what worked:

```
<div id="sectionTwoPage">
```

And the css:

```
#sectionTwoPage:hover {
background-color: silver;
}
```